# How to select (and copy) a column of an org table *without* rectangle selection?

Tags: org-table, copy-paste, rectangle, column, selection

It seems to me that the normal way to copy a column of an org table is by rectangle selection (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002374/how-to-select-a-column-of-a-table-in-emacs-org-mode)). That is, first the column is selected by marking all of it by hand, and then it is copied with `org-table-copy-region` or the like.

What I would like to have is something more ergonomic in step one: The column gets selected based on the position of the cursor only.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two commands `org-table-select-col` and `org-table-copy-col` in the following lisp code allow the selection and the copying of the current table column. You can bind it to the key of your liking and/or insert it via `easy-menu-define-key` into `org-tbl-menu`.

```el
(defun org-table-goto-col-beginning ()
  "Go to beginning of current column and return `point'."
  (interactive)
  (assert (org-table-p) "Not in org-table.")
  (org-table-align)
  (let ((col (org-table-current-column)))
    (goto-char (org-table-begin))
    (org-table-goto-column col))
  (point))

(defun org-table-col-beginning ()
  "Return beginning position of current column."
  (save-excursion
    (org-table-goto-col-beginning)))

(defun org-table-goto-col-end ()
  "Goto end of current column and return `point'."
  (interactive)
  (assert (org-table-p) "Not in org-table.")
  (org-table-align)
  (let ((col (org-table-current-column)))
    (goto-char (1- (org-table-end)))
    (org-table-goto-column col)
    (skip-chars-forward "^|"))
  (point))

(defun org-table-col-end ()
  "Return end position of current column."
  (save-excursion
    (org-table-goto-col-end)))

(defun org-table-select-col ()
  "Select current column."
  (interactive)
  (set-mark (org-table-col-beginning))
  (org-table-goto-col-end))

(defun org-table-copy-col ()
  "Copy current column."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (org-table-copy-region (org-table-goto-col-beginning)
               (org-table-goto-col-end))))
```

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, `save-excursion` doesn't seem to work properly as the cursor is moved *below* the table upon executing `org-table-copy-col`.  How can this be fixed?

Comment: @Timm This is indeed very strange since it works for me. Ubuntu 16.01, emacs 25.1.50.2, org-mode: 8.3.4. I get the behavior as you describe it when I remove the `save-excursion`. Could you post a complete recipe for reproduction (maybe http://www.pastebin.com)?

Comment: I'm using Emacs 24.5.1 on Windows 7 (i686-pc-mingw32) with org-mode  8.2.10. What other information do you need?

Comment: @Timm One solution would be to update to emacs 25. Another solution is to comment out all lines with `assert` statements and to use `(defun org-table-copy-col ()
  "Copy current column."
  (interactive)
  (let ((pt (point)))
    (org-table-copy-region (org-table-goto-col-beginning)
      (org-table-goto-col-end))
    (goto-char pt)))
` instead of the above version of this function.

Answer (score 9):

Actually for `org-table-copy-region` it isn't necessary to mark the exact column width! Just mark the beginning of the column somewhere in a cell, then the end by going down the required number of rows and do `C-c C-x M-w` (for `M-x o-t-c-r`).

Then go to another cell, where you want to add the column and do `C-c C-x C-y` (for `M-x org-table-paste-rectangle`).

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way to go would be to use `org-table-transpose-table-at-point`, which turns columns into rows, and vice versa. Drawback is that horizontal lines get removed. Furthermore the cursor does not remain in the proper column/row.